# Return -1 in Java

Tags: java, return-type

What does return -1 in Java mean? For example if I were trying to convert the following string "98979" into int type without using any library functions:

```
public convertStringToInt(String num){
     int result = 0;
     int zeroAscii = 48;
     int nineAscii = 57;
     for (char c: num.toCharArray()){
         if(c>=zeroAscii && c<=nineAscii){
             result = result*10 + (c-nineAscii);
         }
         else{
             return -1;
         }
     }
     return result;
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide a valid method? You missed the return type of that function.

Comment: Is this your own code?

Comment: This is not a `valid` Java code. `Java` method must have a return type

Comment: -1 is not a special return type in Java.

Comment: Why don't u use Integer.parseInt(numString). Generally Java doesn't use error codes. It uses Exceptions instead (okay, in most cases :))

Comment: There is no special meaning of -1 in java. In the code above, it means the string you want to convert to integer contains characters which are not digit(0-9). So it can not convert the given string to a valid integer and will return -1. It is just returning -1 instead of throwing an exception.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is Not a valid question since OP ask something else providing irrelevant code.

Comment: This is a fine example of terrible code.  Java provides techniques to convert a string to an integer; there is no need to reinvent them.  In this function (it appears to be a C function ported directly to java) -1 indicates that at least one of the characters in the string is not a digit.  Also, this method can never compile.

Comment: -1 in java means: an integer value that is less than zero and has a absolute value of 1.  Besides that, there is no global meaning for -1 in java.  Different methods use -1 to indicate specific conditions, but that meaning varies by method.

Comment: @DwB - And this function deals with ASCII characters unlike java dealing with unicode.

Answer (score 2):

In this case it breaks calculation and give You `-1` result which means that string can not be translated.

Why `-1` ?

Because this code is only for possitive numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is incomplete (no return value specified), but the question is still valid. The meaning of a return value is completely up to the developer to decide. So either yourself or the person(s) who has written the library you use. For well-written libraries, the meaning of the return value will be specified in the documentation.

Comment: I really can't see how this does not answer the original question. The question is what if return -1 has a meaning, with an example, and the answer is that it has no special meaning and is completely up to the developer.

Answer (score 0):

It means nothing per se. Depends on the context program calling your function, which by the way is missing the return type. If you didn't write that code, assume -1 means an error (because the characters belonging to the String to parse are not numerical, i.e. 34E56j)

Answer (score 0):

What return -1 means depends on the method. In this case, it means that a char encountered is not between (including) zeroAscii and nineAscii.

In case of finding an element of a list, you might also get -1, if the element can not be found. This is (afaik) the most common usage of return -1;

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the semantic of the function. If the functions is meant to return int value which is positive (e.g return size, index) then returning negative value indicates that there is some kind of error with the input.

From the java doc of `String.indexOf(int pos)` - Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified character or -1 if the character does not occur.

Answer (score 0):

Your method has no return type, Provide a return type of int in your method.

```
public int convertStringToInt(String num){...
```

And `return -1` means nothing in java, you are just returning a int value, thats it.

The only meaningful explanation for returning -1 seems to be, that the code calling your function expects a return type of int, converted to int from passed String. Hence when the passed String is of not proper numerical format/value the function returns a random gibberish value, in this case -1. Which by the way could very well be -10, -100 etc

Answer (score 0):

It is more of a *design* thing.

```
Integer.parseInt("abc")// throws an error. Because "abc" cannot be converted to an Integer and trying to convert it would definately be foolish. 

String s = "abc";
s.indexOf('x'); // returns -1.
```

This will not lead to an error because (frankly speaking) the designers of the JAVA language *might have had something in mind* when they decided to do so. `indexOf()` cannot have a side effect because `-1` is not an index is java.

Answer (score -1):

Hi first of all your method should have a return type,say String,Integer...
Secondly if your return type was int then return -1 will return -1 or else your result

Hope this helps!!!!